# Apple iPhone Mail does not show hits when searching

Tags: ios, mail.app

Get a mail from Wizzair. If I scroll to the date when I get, I can see in Mail, but when searching "wizzair" it does not show up. Why?

### [image]

[image]

Comment: what happens if you search for wizzair.com or noreply@wizzair.com? I know that I'm often frustrated with the search in mail.app. It seems to default to searching like 5 years back and then (if I'm lucky) slowly fill in newer stuff when I'm looking for something from a few weeks back.

Comment: My first guess is a language issue. I suspect the keyboard is typing different than base English Unicode.   Do search suggestions give any suggestions as you’re typing?

Comment: @dwightk neither wizzair.com nor other works